# How to Eager Load associated data in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Gig Model as follows:

```
public class Gig
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser Artist { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ArtistId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Venue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte GenreId { get; set; }
}
```

In EF6, I was able to Eager Load **Artist** and **Genre** using the following code

```
            var gigs = _context.Attendances
            .Where(a => a.AttendeeId == userId)
            .Select(a => a.Gig)
            .Include(a => a.Artist)
            .Include(a => a.Genre)
            .ToList();
```

But with EF Core, the Artist info or the Genre info is not getting loaded. SQL Profiler shows that there is no INNER JOIN being called on the projection tables.

```
SELECT [a.Gig].[Id], [a.Gig].[ArtistId], [a.Gig].[DateTime], [a.Gig].[GenreId], [a.Gig].[Venue]
FROM [Attendances] AS [a]
INNER JOIN [Gigs] AS [a.Gig] ON [a].[GigId] = [a.Gig].[Id]
WHERE [a].[AttendeeId] = @__userId_0',N'@__userId_0 nvarchar(450)',@__userId_0=N'469d8515-9a04-46af-9276-09c6fead9e10'
```

Can someone help me re-write the query for EF Core please to include the projection tables?

[image: eager load]

UPDATE:
added link to db schema scripts [here](http://www.filedropper.com/gigsissuestackoverflow). posting just the gigs table here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Gigs](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ArtistId] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [GenreId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Venue] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Gigs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Attendances]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Attendances_AspNetUsers_AttendeeId] FOREIGN KEY([AttendeeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Attendances] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Attendances_AspNetUsers_AttendeeId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Attendances]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Attendances_Gigs_GigId] FOREIGN KEY([GigId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Gigs] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Attendances] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Attendances_Gigs_GigId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Gigs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Gigs_AspNetUsers_ArtistId] FOREIGN KEY([ArtistId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Gigs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Gigs_AspNetUsers_ArtistId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Gigs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Gigs_Genres_GenreId] FOREIGN KEY([GenreId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Genres] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Gigs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Gigs_Genres_GenreId]
GO
```

[image: Table relationships]

Comment: Can you please provide the sql scripts to generate the DB schema against this.

Comment: Are the foreign keys between your tables created correctly?  The `Gigs` table needs to have foreign keys to the `ApplicationUser` and `Genre` tables.

Comment: added a link to the scripts as well as provided just the Gigs schema on the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn on EF Core [Logging](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/logging.html), you'll see inside the log something like this:

> The Include operation for navigation: 'a.Gig.Artist' was ignored because the target navigation is not reachable in the final query results.

and similar for `a.Gig.Genre`.

Looks like EF Core at this time cannot handle includes for such queries (that don't start from the resulting entity). The only workaround I can propose is to rewrite the query like this:

```
var gigs = _context.Gigs
    .Where(g => g.Attendances.Any(a => a.AttendeeId == userId))
    .Include(g => g.Artist)
    .Include(g => g.Genre)
    .ToList();
```

or this (translates to better SQL, although the SQL execution plan could be the same):

```
var gigs = (from g in _context.Gigs
            from a in g.Attendances
            where a.AttendeeId == userId
            select g)
    .Include(g => g.Artist)
    .Include(g => g.Genre)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: neither of the above suggestions work because I am not able to get to Attendances from Gigs.

Comment: Just create inverse navigation property of `Attendance.Gig` in `Gig` -> `public ICollection<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }`. Or use manual `join` or `where`. For first `g => _context.Attendances.Any(a => a.GidId == g.Id && a.AttendeeId == userId)`. For second: instead of `from a in g.Attendances` use `join a in _context.Attendances on g.Id equals a.GigId`. But navigation property is better.

Comment: It will not change your current database schema and/or FK associations. But will allow you to easily "navigate" from parent to children which is essential for easy query rewrite.

Comment: I added the nav prop: ICollection<Attendance> Attendances in my Gig model, and the migration created two new keys (GigId1 for FK, and GigId2 for Index). Just executing the code without any other changes didn't get me any data that I was getting before (ie. before I was getting all the field without the associated Aritst and Genre, now I was getting nothing because I added this Nav prop)

Comment: That's strange because I created such model in my EF Core test environment before posting the above answer (the only difference is ApplicationUser properties which is not essential), and it created the correct tables/columns/FKs and both query variants worked (and the original doesn't). There must be something else in your model, can you post the actual entity classes and the configuration (if any)?

Comment: The Join method worked! I am just trying to learn asp.net core and ef core and since this isn't a production app I am going to accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: I am struggling with this query too now.             var gig = _context.Gigs
                .Include(g => g.Attendances.Select(a => a.Attendee))
                .Single(g => g.Id == id && g.ArtistId == userId);    I have added a navigation prop in Gig as follows         public ICollection<Attendance> Attendances { get; private set; }

        public Gig()
        {
            Attendances = new Collection<Attendance>();
        }

Comment: @Reza In EF Core you cannot use `Include` with `Select` as in EF6. EF Core requires `Include` / `ThenInclude` chain, e.g. `.Include(g => g.Attendances).ThenInclude(a => a.Attendee)`

Comment: I tried chaining as so:             var gig = _context.Gigs
                .Include(g => g.Attendances)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Attendee)
                .Single(g => g.Id == id && g.ArtistId == userId);  and got an exception: Invalid column name 'GigId1'.

Invalid column name 'GigId2'.

Comment: Looks like your database and model are out of sync. Also the model might need some configuration.

Comment: Thank you! Yep, I was focused so much on the query that I forgot to make the correct FK updates in the entity models. Much appreciate the hand holding.